# Filter user based on multiple uac status

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory

i need to filter my active directory users based on their UAC Status. i want to achieve that by searching a predefined array of values in an array.
i keep getting errors from powershell no matter how i out my braces (curley or regular).

this is my script. can you tell what am i doing wrong ?

```
$uac = "512", "544", "66048", "66080"

Get-ADUser -Properties *  -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=com" -Filter $uac.IndexOf(userAccountControl) -gt 0 | Select * |OUT-GRIDVIEW
```

i need to make sure i can filter by diffrenet results in the future

Comment: So you want to return any users where `userAccountControl` has one of those 4 _exact_ values? Or do you want to use them as bitmask filters?

Comment: Yes I want to return all the users that have a uac value in that array,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your immediate question is that you're missing something after `-gt`. You probably want `-1` there? (but as Mattias points out, not even that will work).

But there is a better way to do this. It seems like you are trying to find only enabled accounts.

The short answer is that, to avoid having to add more and more numbers to your list, you want to do this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=com" -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
```

**The long answer**

The [`userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) attribute is a bit flag. Bit flags are numbers where every digit in the binary number is a flag that means something. The disabled flag is the second digit (from the right). For example, 514 is this in binary:

> 10 0000 00**1**0

That bold 1 is what means "this is disabled". But any of those other digits can be 1 and it would still be disabled even though the decimal representation is different.

But 512 is not disabled, because that bit is *not* set:

> 10 0000 00**0**0

The only guaranteed way to identify whether that bit is set or not is to use a bitwise operation.

To do that with Active Directory, you would use this LDAP filter:

```
(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
```

That weird number is the matching rule called [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6dd1d7b4-2b2f-4e55-b164-7047c4c5bb00). We use `2`, because it is `10` in binary (the second bit). Because our query has `!` in front, it means: "if the second bit is not set".

Answer (score 1):

`Get-ADUser -Filter` doesn't support running arbritrary code (like `IndexOf()`) against each directory object. But if you want to do an `-in` style query against Active Directory then LDAP, which is what `Get-ADUser` uses "behind-the-scenes" for its query filter, has an OR operator (`|`) that you can use to describe multiple conditions at once.

In your case, the resulting query filter would have to look something like this:

```
(|(userAccountControl=512)(userAccountControl=544)(userAccountControl=66048)(userAccountControl=66080))
```

If you have many individual values you're looking for, or might want to change them in the future, I'd suggest just constructing the LDAP query filter dynamically with a loop and the `-f` string format operator:

```
# exact values we're looking for any of
$uac = "512", "544", "66048", "66080"

# template strings for the LDAP query filter
$LDAPORTemplate = '(|{0})'
$UACEqualsTemplate = '(useraccountcontrol={0})'

# generate the individual filter clause for each possible UAC value
$clauses = foreach($value in $uac){
    $UACEqualsTemplate -f $value
}

# join in a single string
$clauses = $clauses -join ''

# wrap in OR operator
$LDAPQuery = $LDAPORTemplate -f $clauses

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPQUery -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=com" |Select * |Out-GridView
```